# Is there any way to access subcolumns of a data frame in R using bracket [] notation?

Tags: r, syntax, dataframe

So I have this dataset which, after a lot of troubleshooting, I discovered actually had columns within columns that I could access by

```
mydata$user$password
```

The problem is that the functions I have been working on depend on bracket notation to access data. I put all the columnames in a vector which are accessed by for-loops whenever data needs to be pulled from the set. For example:

```
colnames <- c("user.name", "user.password", "business", "misc")
for(name in colnames)
{
  access <- mydata[,name]
  doSomething(access)
}
```

So is there any way I could access these sub-columns (or whatever they are) using the bracket notation or will I have to retool a lot of my code to use the other notation?

Comment: Can you please include the output of these queries as well: `str(mydata)` and `head(mydata)`?

Comment: Is all your data in a list then? Try `mydata[["user"]][["password"]]`

Comment: @Gabe I think he's hoping for something along the lines of treating his data with lapply(mydata,unlist), and then using the names as normal... looks like a JSON  -> data.frame conversion issue. I'm not sure that will work though...

Comment: @Shape I see your point. I was thinking along the lines of easier ways to _access_ the data with the name variables, rather than the possibility of restructuring the data.